# Vsinstr - The application with instrumented binaries is not launching, If visual studio is not installed

Tags: instrumentation

1. I have an application developed in VC++ by using visual studio.
2. The app is having multiple DLLs.
3. To generate code coverage, I am instrumenting few DLLs by using "VsInstr".
4. Replacing the instrumented binaries in the client machine.
5. Now. I am unable to launch the application(No specific errors also). The app is asking me to restart the app.
6. But if I install visual studio(2015) in the machine and launch the app its getting launched successfully.

Should I install Visual studio to launch an application with instrumented DLLs ?
Need help to identify/isolate the dependent file rather than installing the full visual studio.

-- CHANDRU